# Having Open File Function Trouble

Tags: c++

I'm new to c++ coding. I'm trying to write a function that opens  specified ".txt" files(I fed up with coping/pasting multiple times).What I need to realize:

1. Specify filename;
2. read data and save to double(type) array;
3. return array;

As far as I understood, c++ can't return array, but it can return pointer. The problem is: how to use it? Any help will be appreciated. :)

P.S My draft code (it's working):

```
double arr[10];
fstream file;
file.open("input.txt");
if(file.is_open()){
    while(file.good()){
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++){
            file >> arr[i];
        }
    }
    file.close();
}else{ 
    cout<<"[ERROR]: File \"input.txt\" wasn't found!"<<endl;
    cout<<"[INFO]: Terminating program...";
    Sleep(1000);
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: "it's working" - then where is your problem?

Comment: I'd strongly recommend returning a `std::vector`. Avoid all the memory management hassle.

Comment: You can return an array. You can return anything. It might be not efficient though. Instead of using `array`, read about `std::vector`, and passing by reference. For starters. Happy coding. @lethal-guitar OP is new... and stated what they want. The problem is how to refactor this code to work for multiple files. Why be sarcastic...

Comment: So what this all boils down to is `"how should I return an array`"?  If it does, why show code that opens files?

Comment: You can actually return that vector by value because you'd get a move instead of a copy.

Comment: @noobProgrammer Not really. It would be Return Value Optimization, move is kind of different. It's more like copy ellision.

Comment: @lethal-guitar `I dunno how to write as a function. Moreover I dunno how to use it` Yet your code has calls to functions such as `Sleep`, `exit(0)`. If you don't know functions, you sure are using them in the code you posted.  I suggest you read up on how to create a function and call it (you already know how to call functions).

Comment: @luk32 returning a movable object (like a `vector`) and assigning to (or constructing an) outside variable will always result in a move even if the compiler doesn't perform RVO. So in general, you can cheaply return by value in C++ 11, which you couldn't before.

Comment: @lethal-guitar Fair enough, but RVO takes precedence, and will be performed even if the compiler does not support c++11 or the object is immovable. It is the same argument. If you write a descent code that will use a move instead of RVO upon returning a local variable, you will have my most respect, sir. Also, RVO is more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I dunno how to write as a function. Moreover I dunno how to use it

To start, try this:

```
std::vector<double> theFunction(const std::string &filename)
{
    std::vector<double> arr(10);

    std::fstream file(filename);

    if (file) 
    {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < 10 && file.good(); i++)
            file >> arr[i];
    }

    return arr;
}

std::vector<double> result = theFunction("input.txt");

if (result.empty())
    // Can not read the file
```